# Inequality comparison between SymPy Relationals

Tags: python, sympy

I have defined 2 functions in PINNs (NVIDIA modulus) at the beginning and then I need to compare the absolute value of them to work out conclusions afterward.

```py
# spacial coordinates
x, y = Symbol("x"), Symbol("y")

# time coordinates
t = Symbol("t")

# make input variables
input_variables = {"x": x, "y": y, "t": t}

# Symbols
u, v = Symbol("u"), Symbol("v")
sigma_xx, sigma_xy, sigma_yy = Symbol("sigma_xx"), Symbol("sigma_xy"), Symbol("sigma_yy")

# displacement components
u = Function("u")(*input_variables)
v = Function("v")(*input_variables)

# stress components predicted
sigma_xx = Function("sigma_xx")(*input_variables)
sigma_yy = Function("sigma_yy")(*input_variables)
sigma_xy = Function("sigma_xy")(*input_variables)

# damage variable
# Variables of interest: p, f
p = Function("p")(*input_variables)
d = Function("d")(*input_variables)

if p < sigma_xx:
    print("hello")
else:
    print("try again")
```

The above code produces the error:

```py
raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

How can I properly compare these? I expected it to compare the sympy variable to float or another sympy variable of the same type so I could draw further conclusions.

Also, if I wanted to compare those to, say, a `float` or an `int`, how could that be done?

Comment: Since `p` and `sigma_xx` are undefined functions the condition tested in the `if` is `p(x, y, t) < σₓₓ(x, y, t)`. It is impossible to say if this is true or false so it is impossible to choose a branch for the `if/else`.